# How can one enlarge the search control in a FuelUX 3.x repeater?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, fuelux

This is a simple customization issue that is not covered by the tutorial: the search control is too small—any reasonable query will not fit. How can one make it longer (possibly occupying all remaining free space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a CSS rule that overrides: `.fuelux .repeater-search { float: left; width: 200px };` such as `.myapp .fuelux .repeater-search { float: none; width: auto; };`

Then it will look like this

[image]

As long as you are using the `.repeater-search` class you should be able to edit the markup into Bootstrap columns, etc.

Comment: Any way to make it occupy all space *except* for the drop down and the type selector? I'd like everything to be on the same line.

Comment: This goes into however you would make columns on any website. If you don't mind everything being left aligned you could inline-block everything in one container div